# Proof that pointwise equicontinuity on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ implies uniform equicontinuity.

Tags: real-analysis, equicontinuity

I have an idea of the proof of the above statement, but I'm not entirely sure if it's right. Any comments would be appreciated. This question was supposedly answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710146/if-the-domain-is-a-compact-set-pointwise-equicontinuity-implies-uniform-equicon) but the answer doesn't address the question at all.

Work so far:

Suppose not, i.e. that there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $\delta > 0$ and $x,t \in [a,b]$, $|x-t| < \delta$ but $|f_k(x) - f_k(t)| \geq \epsilon$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Fix this $\epsilon$.

We are given a family of functions $f_n:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined on a compact interval $[a,b]$, and that this family is pointwise equicontinuous. Pointwise equicontinuity of {$f_n$} implies that each $f_n$ is continuous, and since the domain is compact, we have that each $f_n$ is uniformly continuous. In particular $f_k$ is uniformly continuous, but this contradicts the hypothesis above.

Comment: This proof seems to be flawed. A proper proof by contradiction here would suppose $\exists \epsilon>0: \nexists \delta>0\: \forall k\in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $K \subset \Bbb{R}$ be compact; let $A \neq \varnothing$; let $f_{\alpha}: K \to \Bbb{R}$ for all $\alpha \in A$; let $\{ f_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha \in A}$ be pointwise equicontinuous. For every $c \in K$, if $\varepsilon > 0$ then there is some $\delta_{c} > 0$ such that $x \in B_{K}^{c}(\delta_{c})$ implies $|f_{\alpha}(x) - f_{\alpha}(c)| < \varepsilon/2$ for all $\alpha \in A$. (Here $B_{K}^{c}(\delta_{c})$ denotes the open ball formed over $K$ of center $c$ and radius $\delta_{c}$.) We have $\bigcup_{c \in K}B_{K}^{c}(\delta_{c}/2) = K$, implying by compactness of $K$ that there are some $c_{1},\dots, c_{n} \in K$ such that 
$$
\bigcup_{j=1}^{n}B_{K}^{c_{j}}(\delta_{c_{j}}/2) = K.
$$
If $x \in K$, then there is some $1 \leq j \leq n$ such that $x \in B_{K}^{c_{j}}(\delta_{c_{j}}/2)$ and hence $\in B_{K}^{c_{j}}(\delta_{c_{j}})$; if $|x-y| < \min_{1 \leq i \leq n}\delta_{c_{i}}/2$, then $|y - c_{j}| \leq |y-x| + |x-c_{j}| < \delta_{c_{j}}/2 + \delta_{c_{j}}/2 = \delta_{c_{j}}$, implying that $y \in B_{K}^{c_{j}}(\delta_{c_{j}})$, implying that
$$
|f_{\alpha}(x) - f_{\alpha}(y)| \leq |f_{\alpha}(x) - f_{\alpha}(c_{j})| + |f_{\alpha}(c_{j}) - f_{\alpha}(y)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon
$$
for all $\alpha \in A$;
this shows the desired uniform equicontinuity.

Comment: That was very clear, thank you.